# parseArgs, throws type error exact same sample code in docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
import { parseArgs } from 'node:util'

const args = []

const options = {
  t: {
    type: "string"
  }
}

const { values, positionals } = parseArgs({ args, options })
```

This code taken from the example code in the documentation throws this:

```
src/main.ts:13:51 - error TS2322: Type '{ t: { type: string; }; }' is not assign
able to type 'ParseArgsOptionsConfig'.
  Property 't' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ParseArgsOptionConfig'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "boolean"'.

13 const { values, positionals } = parseArgs({ args, options })
                                                     ~~~~~~~
```

What the hell does this mean?

### Edit

If I explicitly cast `t: 'string'` to
`t: 'string' as 'string'` it passes. If anyone can explain this problem better, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't care I am using version 20, it is supposed to work this is the simplest example.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer gives the correct diagnosis of the problem: TypeScript infers the `type` key as holding any string, rather than specifically `"string"` or `"boolean"`, which is what the types require.

But a better fix to this is to add `as const` to the options definition:

```
const options = {
  t: {
    type: "string"
  }
} as const
```

That will tell TypeScript to infer the type more narrowly, which will make the types work. And by doing so you will get better type inference for the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

for vanilla js users (JSDoc):

```js
import { parseArgs } from 'node:util'

const args = []

/** @type Object */
const options = {
  t: {
    type: "string"
  }
}

const { values, positionals } = parseArgs({ args, options })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've arrived here because of TypeScript errors in the sample code from the [User-defined arguments section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/workflows/seeding#user-defined-arguments) of the Prisma seeding guide, this resolves the errors:

```js
const options = {
  environment: {
    type: "string",
  },
} as const;
```